# Is there a way to read the file character by character in int format

Tags: python

I am trying to read the file character by character.
Below is the example input format

```
0    2,3,4
1    3
2    0,4
```

But i get error

```
"invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0    2,3,4' "
```

My code is :

```
import itertools
import sys


for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()    
    line = line.split("\t")    
    key = int(line[0])
```

I have also tried using convert to float but still the error persists.

```
for line in sys.stdin:   
    line = line.strip()    
    line = line.split("\t")    
    key = int(float(line[0]))
```

`Error : "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0    2,3,4' "`

Can somebody have different idea to convert this to integer?

Comment: do you want `line[0]` to be first number of every line? If so remove `\t` from `split`

Comment: yes  line[0] should be the first number in every line

Comment: first check `print(line[0])` to see what you have in variable. Probably you will have to use another `split()` to split it in list of numbers. Maybe this split will need `space` instead of `\t`. You can also try `split()` without argument and it will use `\t` and `space` at the same time to split it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your input, it contains white spaces and you can not convert white space char in base 10.
You can try below code

```
import itertools
import sys


for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()    
    line = line.replace("    ",",")
    print(line[0])
```

I have added other version as well
    import itertools
    import sys

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()    
    line = line.replace("    ",",")
    for i in line.split(","):
        print (int(i))
```

Comment: This is doing nothing to resolve the problem of tokenizing the line into `int()`s.

Comment: I have answered what is asked in the problem statement, He is just trying to read the 0th characters, A simple modification in my code and we can read each character.

Answer (score 0):

You are, and want to be, reading the file line by line.  Then just split on whitespace and commas, and convert each token.

```py
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    for spaced in line.strip().split():
        for token in spaced.split(","):
            print(int(token))
```

You are not using `itertools` for anything so I dropped that import.